# How to show table filtering it by class inside "td"?

Tags: jquery

I need to filter multiple tables using class `.max-kwota` inside `td >span`.

Now when I'm doing `console.log(v);` I receiving all values in one sting.
 So the question is, how to configure `var v` if i need to compare it with value from my input.

```js
$('input[name="test"]').on('change', function(a, b) {
  var value = this.value;
  $('table >tbody').hide();
  if (value == 'All') {
    $('table >tbody').show();
  }
  if (value == 'Under 3000') {
    $('table >tbody').filter(function(a, b) {
      var v = $('.max-kwota').text();
      console.log(v);
      return 3000 > v;
    }).show();
  }
  if (value == 'Under 10000') {
    $('table >tbody').filter(function(a, b) {
      var v = $('.max-kwota').text();
      return 10000 > v;
    }).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="All" checked name="test"><label>All</label>
<input type="radio" value="Under 3000" name="test"><label> Under 3000</label>
<input type="radio" value="Under 10000" name="test"><label>Under 10000</label>



<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="max-kwota">500</span></td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="max-kwota">4000</span></td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="max-kwota">11000</span></td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue comes from the fact that you are selecting **all** elements with the class `max-kwota` in your filter callback function. What you want is to select elements that are contain in that specific `tbody` element. To do that, you can provide context to the selector, i.e. by providing `this` in the second argument:

```
var v = $('.max-kwota', this).text();
```

Meanwhile, the `.text()` method returns the `textContent` of the node, i.e. it will be `typeof string`. You will need to convert it to a number first: this can be done by using the unary operator `+`, i.e.:

```
var v = +$('.max-kwota', this).text();
```

Do note that, however, this only works if you have a single `.max-kwota` element **per** `<tbody>` element.

```js
$('input[name="test"]').on('change', function(a, b) {
  var value = this.value;
  $('table  >tbody').hide();
  if (value === 'All') {
    $('table > tbody').show();
  }
  if (value === 'Under 3000') {
    $('table > tbody').filter(function(a, b) {
      var v = +$('.max-kwota', this).text();
      return 3000 > v;
    }).show();
  }
  if (value === 'Under 10000') {
    $('table > tbody').filter(function(a, b) {
      var v = +$('.max-kwota', this).text();
      return 10000 > v;
    }).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="All" checked name="test"><label>All</label>
<input type="radio" value="Under 3000" name="test"><label> Under 3000</label>
<input type="radio" value="Under 10000" name="test"><label>Under 10000</label>



<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="max-kwota">500</span></td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="max-kwota">4000</span></td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="max-kwota">11000</span></td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank  you for explanation! That's work work perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle display of your whole table.

```
$('input[name="test"]').on('change', function(a, b) {
  var value = this.value;
  if (value == 'All') {
    $(".max-kwota").parents('table').show();
  }
  if (value == 'Under 3000') {
        $(".max-kwota").filter(function() {
           return !($(this).text() > 3000);
        }).parents('table').hide();
  }
  if (value == 'Under 10000') {
        $(".max-kwota").filter(function() {
           return !($(this).text() > 10000);
        }).parents('table').hide();
  }
});
```